# MySql Slave Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.00116, end_log_pos 8631

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql5.7

I have Active-Passive-Master-Master replication setup in Mysql with version 5.7.
I found the below error in MySql2 (passive Master server) but the status show it's in sync with Master server (mysql1).

'*Last_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table test_db.test; Can't find record in 'test', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.00116, end_log_pos 8631*'

Also, mysql1 reports 210 records in test_db.test whereas mysql2 reports 200 records in the same table.

**Master Status**:
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.00117 | 8465|              |                  |                   |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+

**Slave Status**:

Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host: mysql1.local
Master_User: repl
Master_Port: 3306
Connect_Retry: 60
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.00117
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 8465
Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.00848
Relay_Log_Pos: 8631
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.00116
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: No
Replicate_Do_DB:
Replicate_Ignore_DB:
Replicate_Do_Table:
Replicate_Ignore_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
Last_Errno: 1032
Last_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table test_db.test; Can't find record in 'test', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.00116, end_log_pos 8631
Skip_Counter: 0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 8631
Relay_Log_Space: 1992196592
Until_Condition: None
Until_Log_File:
Until_Log_Pos: 0
Master_SSL_Allowed: No
Master_SSL_CA_File:
Master_SSL_CA_Path:
Master_SSL_Cert:
Master_SSL_Cipher:
Master_SSL_Key:
Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
Last_IO_Errno: 0
Last_IO_Error:
Last_SQL_Errno: 1032
Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table test_db.test; Can't find record in 'test', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.00116, end_log_pos 8631
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
Master_Server_Id: 10
Master_UUID: f905decf-cca8-11ea-9c80
Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
SQL_Delay: 0
SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
Slave_SQL_Running_State:
Master_Retry_Count: 86400
Master_Bind:
Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 201022 13:50:58
Master_SSL_Crl:
Master_SSL_Crlpath:
Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
Executed_Gtid_Set:
Auto_Position: 0
Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
Channel_Name:
Master_TLS_Version: